# Dynamic filter Table error Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, return-value

I have a filter in search in my website. so I need to get the brandname of company that have a product in year

and I wan to inter more that one value of year or nulll

I used a split function to return Table of years

```
declare @test nvarchar(50) = '1991,1997'


select BrandName from Item where DisplayPrice =1
 and YearMan in (CASE WHEN @test is not null THEN (select * from split(@test,',')) ELSE YearMan END)
```

Split Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN

DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)


    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
     BEGIN
         SELECT
          @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
          @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

         IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
          INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
     END

        IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
         INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
```

END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
select BrandName
from Item
where DisplayPrice =1
 and (@test IS NULL OR YearMan in (select item from split(@test,','))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test nvarchar(50) = '1991,1997'

select  BrandName 
from    Item 
where   DisplayPrice =1
and     @test is not null 
and     YearMan in (select * from dbo.split(@test,','))
union all
select  BrandName 
from    Item 
where   DisplayPrice =1
and     @test is null 

-- or

declare @test nvarchar(50) = '1991,1997'
declare @array table (yyyy smallint primary key);
insert  @array (yyyy)
select  * from dbo.split(@test,',');

select  BrandName 
from    Item 
where   DisplayPrice =1
and     @test is not null 
and     YearMan in (select yyyy from @array)
union all
select  BrandName 
from    Item 
where   DisplayPrice =1
and     @test is null
```